# MetaTrader Terminal [ History Center ] section: missing data within the platform?

Tags: metatrader4, metatrader5

I have recently downloaded MT4 & MT5. In both of these platforms where the historical data section should be ( in the dropdown of the tools section ), it is missing in both and I cannot seem to find a way to access this function.

It just doesn't seem to be in the platform at all?

My intention is to carry on with my research on backtesting data.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The broad answer below, and the brevity of the post, suggests that this question needed an [mcve]. It furthermore appears to be abandoned, so I am casting a close vote for now.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1) define the problem:

Given the text above, it seems that your MetaTrader Terminal downloads have been installed, but do not allow you to inspect the `(Menu)->[Tools]->[History Center]`. If this is the case, check this with Support personnel from the Broker company you have downloaded these platforms from, as there are possible ways, how some Brokers may adapt the platform, including the objected behaviour.

---

### Step 2) explain the target behaviour:

Your initial post has mentioned that your intention is to gain access to data due to "research on backtesting data".

If this is the valid target, your goal can be achieved also by taking an MT4 platform from any other Broker, be it with or without data, and next, importing `{ PERIOD_M1 | PERIOD_M5 | ... }`-records, via an MT4 [History Center] <kbd>**`F2`**</kbd> import interface. Just enough to follow the product documentation.

If your Quantitative Modelling requires tick-based data with a Market-Access Venue "fidelity", there was no such a way so far available for an end-user to import and resample some externally collected tick-data for MetaTrader Terminal platform.

---

### Step 3) demonstrate your research efforts + steps already performed:

This community will always welcome active members, rather than "shouting" things like "Any idea?" or "ASAP" and "I need this and that, help me!".

Showing efforts, that have been spent on solving the root cause are warmly welcome, as Stack Overflow strongly encourages members to post high quality questions, formulated in a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example of code, that can re-run + re-produce the problem under test. Using PrintScreens for UI-states are ok for your type of issue, to show the blocking state and explain the context.